# How to extend app.js methods/data/watch from laravel blade view file without creating components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

### I'm new in vue.js.

**My `app.js` is:**

```
import { store } from './store';
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    mounted(){
        ...
    },
    methods:{
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm using **laravel** and I don't want every time to create components for very small reason.
Without making components `app.js` will be full of methods whose all are not useful in every pages. That's why I want a way to extend `app.js` from my `home.blade.php` file's

```
@section(scripts)
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
@endsection
```

(without creating any component).

Or, Updating/add in `data:{ ... }` & `methods:{ ... }` using that `<script> .. </script>` in **`*.blade.php`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've found a solution!

## Use `Mixin`

Create `mixin.js` file besides `app.js`

## For example

```
export var custom = {
  data: {
    show: true
  },
  methods: {
    hide: function(){
      this.show = false;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    ...
  },

  ...

};
```

and, in `app.js` file:

```
import { store } from './store';
import { custom } from './mixin';  //Import mixin
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mixins: [custom],  // Add mixin var here
    store,
});

/*
  [note: for multiple: import {custom1, custom2, ...} and define [custom1, custom2, ...] ]
*/
```

More details: *[Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)*